# Flutter Remove List Item from another widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a listview builder that generates a list

```
ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Tag(
                    callback: (list) => setState(() => hashList = list),
                    tag: snapshot[index].data["title"],
                    list: hashList,
                  );
                },
              )
```

The tag function then adds the item to another list depending on if its selected, then removed if its clicked again.

This is the handle selected function in Tag

```
void _handleOnPressed() {
setState(() {
  isSelected = !isSelected;
  isSelected
      ? _animationController.forward()
      : _animationController.reverse();
  isSelected ? widget.list.add(
      Container(
        height: 30,
        color: Colors.green,
        child: Text(widget.tag, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.purple),),
      )): widget.list.removeAt(????));
});
```

}
}

I am trying to figure out how to remove it.

When this list was a text list, I could add and remove based on the next. But right now a container is being added to the list, and I want to delete the item either at that index, or the entire container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried approch like this,
compare the tag if that matches with you original list,

```
int removeTagAt(){
for(int i=0;i<snapshot.lenght;i++)
{
if(widget.tag==snapshot[index])
return i;
}
}
```

and then call,

```
  Container(
        height: 30,
        color: Colors.green,
        child: Text(widget.tag, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.purple),),
      )): widget.list.removeAt(removeTagAt()));
```